# How to create a positive definite covariance matrix from an adjacency matrix?

Tags: probability, statistics, graph-theory, random-graphs

I am currently trying to create a covariance matrix from an adjacency matrix. I would like to create the covariance matrix by the following two steps:

1) Wherever there is a connection, I would place a correlation parameter $\rho$.

2) Replace the diagonals of all $0$'s with a common variance, like $1$.

As a reproducible example, consider the following adjacency matrix for $5$ nodes:

$$
A = \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
\end{pmatrix}
$$

We can see from the first row that node $1$ is connected with node $4$ and node $5$.

From this, we replace all the $1$'s with a common correlation parameter $\rho$ and put a $1$ in the diagonal to get:

$$
\Sigma = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & \rho & \rho \\ 
0 & 1 & \rho & 0 & \rho \\ 
0 & \rho & 1 & \rho & 0 \\ 
\rho & 0 & \rho & 1 & 0 \\ 
\rho & \rho & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{pmatrix}
$$

HOWEVER, this covariance matrix is **not positive definite.** if I introduce say, $\rho = 0.9$.

Hence, if I fit a multivariate normal model on this covariance matrix, I would get errors in programs. Is there a way around it?

I also noticed if I increase the marginal variances ($1$ above), then the problem goes away. Is there a reason why? Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean conditional independence instead of full independence between $i$ and $j$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can reduce the value of $\rho$, it will be positive definite eventually.

From Gershgorin circle theorem, let $R_i= \sum_{j \neq i} |a_{ij}|$, let $D(a_{ii}, R_i)$ be the closed disc centered at $a_{ii}$ with radius $R_i$, each eigenvalue lies in at least one of the disc.

For your particular example $R_i = 2 |\rho|$ and $a_{ii}=1$. If $\rho < \frac12$, then it will be positive definite for sure.

Comment: How did you get that $\rho < \frac{1}{2}$ implies that the covariance matrix will be positive definite?

Comment: using Gershgorin circle theorem, the eigenvalues are in $(1-2\rho, 1+2\rho)$

Comment: thanks, I am having a hard time seeing how the range $(1-2\rho, 1+2\rho)$ implies $\rho < \frac{1}{2}$. Is there a key theorem I am missing?

Comment: I made a mistake, should be $(1-2|\rho|, 1+ 2|\rho|)$. if $|\rho|<\frac12$, then the eigenvalues are positive, then it is positive definite.